# Shield UI Bar Chart hierarchical data

Tags: bar-chart, shieldui

I would like to know whether it is possible to perform data zooming, or the so called drill in using a Shield UI Chart graph. For instance I have some data for a specific period. A year. Than clicking one of the bars for the month of that year i see the data for the month's weeks and so on.
I looked on what is available online, however i couldn't find anything for the Javascript version of the chart.

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of fact there is some good example available online, that i will get you a link below. As far as it gets to the JavaScript version of the chart- such functionality is not possible. However the ASP.NET Bar Chart does allow it.
Here is a link, that i share instead of lacing the code that is also available online:

[Code](https://demos.shieldui.com/aspnet/aspnet-chart/drill-down)